# XSLT node-set based on static vs. string data

Tags: xslt-1.0

This works with static data:

```
<xsl:variable name="ExtensionData3">
<images>
    <image id="10842" width="2450" height="2200" default="1" />
    <image id="10543" width="2450" height="2200" default="0" />
    <image id="10544" width="2450" height="2200" default="0" />
</images>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ExtensionData3)/images/image[@default='1']/@id" />
```

How do I get this to work with dynamic data?:

```
<xsl:variable name="ExtensionData3">
<xsl:value-of select="XMLData" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ExtensionData3)/images/image[@default='1']/@id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get this to work with dynamic data?:
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="ExtensionData3">
>   <xsl:value-of select="XMLData" />
> </xsl:variable>
> <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($ExtensionData3)/images/image[@default='1']/@id"
> ```
>
> />

**The error is in this line**:

> ```
>   <xsl:value-of select="XMLData" />
> ```

This outputs (creates a text node with) the string value of the first `XMLData` child of the current node.

But you don't want string -- you want *nodes* to be copied.

**The correct way to do this is**:

```
   <xsl:copy-of select="XMLData" />
```

**Even better, in this case you don't need at all to create an RTF and then to convert it to a temporary tree -- just use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="ExtensionData3" select="XMLData"/>
```